# Error while running Rscript using crontab: ELF file OS ABI invalid

Tags: r, linux, cron, rscript, r-googlesheets

I am running an `Rscript` using `crontab`. In that `Rscript` command, I am trying to load `googlesheets` package using `library(googlesheets)`. Note, I have already installed `googlesheets` package is already installed.

I am getting this error:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
unable to load shared object '/home/sparavas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/purrr/libs/purrr.so':
/home/sparavas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/purrr/libs/purrr.so: ELF file OS ABI invalid
In addition: Warning message:
package 'googlesheets' was built under R version 3.2.3
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'googlesheets'
Execution halted
```

When I run the same script from terminal, I am not getting this error. **This errors comes only when ran through `crontab`.**

I also tried to get below sessionInfo (if this might help to detect the problem) :

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] methods   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.11.1 reshape2_1.4.1  DIVER_0.1.1     hash_2.2.6
[5] dplyr_0.4.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1    digest_0.6.8   withr_1.0.1    assertthat_0.1 R6_2.1.0
 [6] plyr_1.8.2     DBI_0.3.1      magrittr_1.5   stringi_0.4-1  tools_3.2.0
[11] stringr_1.0.0  parallel_3.2.0 memoise_1.0.0
```

I also tried reinstalling packages `purrr`, `dplyr`, `googlesheets`. Please suggest what I am missing.

Also what does:

> ELF file OS ABI invalid

mean?

Comment: Is there something to do with R version as when I run sessionInfo() from terminal, I see R version 3.2.3 is being used and when the cron tab runs sessionInfo(), the R version is 3.2.0